# Dataframe.loc on non-unique index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` with a non-unique index.
I want to use `.loc` on a`dataframe`.

```
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14], ['tom', 12], ['tom', 64]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
df.set_index('Name', inplace = True)
```

When I try

```
df.loc['tom': 'Age']
```

> KeyError: "Cannot get left slice bound for non-unique label: 'tom'"

Why is that? Can I only `.loc` on `dataframes` with unique indexes?

Comment: @9769953 I edited my Q accordingly

Comment: You used `:` instead of the `,` in the loc try `df.loc['tom', 'Age']` because 'Age' is a column

Comment: Commenting on Ben.T's comment: is your intention to select a range of indices (in which case, your sample doesn't make sense, since 'tom' selects one or more rows, and 'Age' selects a column), or is your intention to select multiple rows for a particular column? In the latter case, indeed, use a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implementation is wrong. `Age` is not an element of `Name` index and moreover if you want to slice between rows then rows must be unique. Suppose you can't apply `.loc[]` on `Name` index like `'tom':'nick'` because `Name` are not unique.

Check [pandas.loc[]](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for more details.

**You could do something like this:**

```
import pandas as pd


data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14], ['tom', 12], ['tom', 64]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
df.set_index('Name', inplace = True)
df = df.loc['tom', 'Age']

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
Name
tom    10
tom    12
tom    64
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```